My Python Toplevel windows open in different positions on my screen as I open and close them
I have a button that opens a Toplevel window in a Python app. I open the window and the widget appears just fine, but if I close and reopen the Toplevel window with the same button, the window opens in a position Southwest of where it had opened previously. Eventually, the window opens at a point near the top left of my screen and then begins the incremental process downward as I continue to open and close the Toplevel window.
Is there a way to fix where the Toplevel window appears relative to the root frame?
I was expecting the app to always display the window in the same location. I have tried using the lift() parameter to set the widget above the root frame, but this did not help:
Function that creates toplevel below:
  def EXIT1(self):
        self.exitsure = tk.Toplevel()
        self.exitsure.resizable(0,0)

        self.submit1['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.submit2['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.submit3['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.submit4['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.backup['state'] = 'disabled'

        self.areyousure = tk.Label(self.exitsure, text="Are you sure you want to give " + self.output1.cget("text") + " a point?")
        self.areyousure.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.ExitYes = tk.Button(self.exitsure, text="Yes", command=self.rewrite1)
        self.ExitYes.grid(column=0, row=2)

        self.NoYes = tk.Button(self.exitsure, text="No", command=self.Destroy_Enable)
        self.NoYes.grid(column=2, row=2)
        self.exitsure.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closed)


Use geometry() to put the window at specific position.

Change the index to ones. self.ExitYes.grid(column=0, row=1) and self.NoYes.grid(column=1, row=2)

When a new window opens, the Window Manager (i.e. Windows) chooses a place on screen for it. Stacking downward and rightward is builtin Windows (the OS) behaviour since ancient times.
As already commented, the geometry method can be used to place a window. You can give new position and/or width and height.
frame = tkinter.Tk()
frame.geometry("+300+500") # places the window without resizing
frame.geometry("800x700") # changes window size
frame.geometry("800x700+300+500") # both at once

If you want to use values from the parent window (e.g. to position a dialog in the middle), you can get them with the winfo methods.

parent.winfo_rootx(), parent.winfo_rooty() gets position relative to the screen's corner,
parent.winfo_width(), parent.winfo_height() gets the size.

